# Jenkins pack deletar todos os diretórios da pasta exceto 1

Tags: php, jenkins

Tenho a estrutura de diretórios assim

- ${src.web.dir}/templates/assets_clientes/

  - cliente1
  - cliente2
  - cliente3

Eu preciso remover todas as pastas internas incluindo .svn menos a pasta cliente3 e seu arquivos e diretórios (cliente3 é ${env.PASTA_ASSETS})

meu build.xml

```
<target name="pack" depends="config">

    <echo message="Retirando pastas de Clientes..." />

    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" >
        <fileset dir="${src.web.dir}/templates/assets_clientes/" >
            <include name="**/*" />
            <exclude name="." />
            <exclude name="${env.PASTA_ASSETS}" />
        </fileset>
    </delete>

    <zip destfile="${nome.arquivo}">
        ....
    </zip>
</target>
```

Comment: Pergunta deveria está em português.

Comment: não entendi o motivo mas ok, está em português.

Comment: Porque o idioma do site é **Português**. Se quiser fazer perguntas em inglês, deverá ser no Stack em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A melhor forma que consegui foi essa:

```
<delete includeEmptyDirs="true" >
        <fileset dir="${src.web.dir}/templates/assets_clientes" includes="**/*" defaultexcludes="false">
            <exclude name="**${env.PASTA_ASSETS}/**/*" />
        </fileset>
    </delete>

    <zip destfile="${nome.arquivo}">
     ...
```

Mas os arquivos .svn continuam... mas meu problema foi resolvido.